# Facebook sharing a post Exception

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to share a page from my website to Facebook using Facebook  S.D.K but when i click on share button a base exception is shared instead of the page that i need to share. I don't know why this is happen. Plus, i can't find any error in log files.I have followed all the steps that Facebook require.

Code used to generate metadata:

```
    $this->registerMetaTag([
    'property'=>"og:url",
    'content' =>Yii::$app->params['current-url'].'/view-inspiration?Tip='.$AllTips->ADS_ID
]);    
     $this->registerMetaTag([
    'property'=>"og:type",
    'content' =>'website',
    ]);
    $this->registerMetaTag([
        'property'=>"og:title",
        'content' =>'Nuptial'
    ]);
    $this->registerMetaTag([
        'property'=>"og:description",
        'content' =>'Wedding Provider Website'
    ]);
    $this->registerMetaTag([
        'property'=>"og:image",
        'content' =>Yii::$app->params['current-url']. $AllTips->ADS_IMG,
    ]);
```

Facebook Script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=dssdf&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Facebook Share Button :

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.nuptial.me/view-inspiration?Tip=<?=$AllTips->ADS_ID?>" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nuptial.me%2Fview-inspiration%3FTip%3D6&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
```

[image: This is what is shown when i share the page]

Please i need help.
Thank You.